# How do I change my children's apple IDs so that they are anonymous?

Tags: icloud, apple-id, privacy, family-sharing, children

I originally created apple IDs for my kids in a format like this: FirstMLast@icloud.com

Since then, I've become more privacy conscious and would like to replace these with anonymous accounts that protect my kids' identities and limit their potential for being doxxed.

They have their own devices and are part of our Apple Family, with ScreenTime already configured. They receive emails at their email addresses, texts with iMessage, and have made app and music purchases we share with Family Sharing. They also have their accounts added to our laptops and have some data stored in the cloud associated with their account.

Should I start over from scratch creating new apple IDs and adding them to our Apple Family?  Or is there some way to "fix" their old ones?  I don't want to lose their purchases or data, though I recognize I may have to do some work to copy/backup/restore them.

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202667

Comment: Personally, I’d keep those IDs for your kids; they’re  cleanly formatted AppleIDs.  They don’t need to give that out.  Just get email addresses with aliases (Gmail and Outlook have this capability) and use that address with your AppleID.  Give that out.  If spam gets out of control, you can create a new alias (kill the old one) and continue on with the same account.

Comment: You can create aliases within iCloud too, no need for a second service

Comment: Thank you all for those suggestions, they sound much simpler than what I was planning! I’ll give this approach a try.

Comment: Be sure to come back and self-answer with how you ultimately  solved this.  And if you run into difficultly, just update your question.  Oh, and welcome to Ask Different!

Comment: AppleID can get exposed to others via Facetime, Messages, and other services. But  up to three forwarding email aliases can be created so that at least email is more pseudonymous. You can lock down contact info that's usable with Facetime and Messages, and which contact info is used to originate communication.

Comment: Created an alias. Now trying to figure out how to send mail from that alias. (So recipient doesn't see the real address.)

Comment: Figured that out I think. Under iCloud mail, click Settings, Preferences, under Accounts is where you add the email alias. Then under Composing, SEND FROM, is where you identify which addresses are used for sending. I unchecked the box for the one that revealed identity.  However the 2 test mails I sent so far don't appear to have worked.  Maybe icloud alias emails are delayed?

Comment: I tried sending a test email to the newly created alias but it bounced back: Your message wasn't delivered to XXX@icloud.com because the address couldn't be found, or is unable to receive mail.

Comment: It took a while before emails started working, and they initially went to junk, but I think it's working now.

Comment: The instructions here helped switch Messages and FaceTime to the new aliases: https://www.idownloadblog.com/2016/04/29/add-new-email-to-imessage-in-ios/